# ESP8266 is reset while overwriting the existing database

Tags: reset, esp8266

If the test program is started by deleting (resetting) the database file each time it is run, the procedures are working.

```
/*
    This creates two empty databases, populates values, and retrieves them back
    from the SPIFFS file system.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <FS.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"
}
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

sqlite3* db1;

void WiFiOff() {
    wifi_station_disconnect();
    wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
    wifi_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
    wifi_fpm_open();
    wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF);
}

const char* data = "Callback function called";
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
    int i;
    Serial.printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        Serial.printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int db_open(const char* filename, sqlite3** db) {
    int rc = sqlite3_open(filename, db);
    if (rc) {
        Serial.printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
        return rc;
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    return rc;
}

char* zErrMsg = 0;
int db_exec(sqlite3* db, const char* sql) {
    Serial.println(sql);
    long start = micros();
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        Serial.printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    Serial.print(F("Time taken:"));
    Serial.println(micros() - start);
    return rc;
}


void OpenDatabase();
void CreateTable();
void InsertValues();
void SelectValues();

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(74880);    

    system_update_cpu_freq(SYS_CPU_160MHZ);
    WiFiOff();

    if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
        return;
    }

    // list SPIFFS contents
    Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next()) {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long)fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");

    // remove existing file
    SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db");

    sqlite3_initialize();

    OpenDatabase();
    CreateTable();
    InsertValues();
    SelectValues();    */

    // list SPIFFS contents
    dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next()) {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long)fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
    
}

void loop() {
}

void OpenDatabase() {    
    int rc;
    // Open databases
    File db_file_obj_1;
    vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);
    if (db_open("/test1.db", &db1)) return;    
}

void CreateTable() {    
    int rc;
    // Create Table
    rc = db_exec(db1, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (id INTEGER, content);");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);        
        return;    
    }    
}

void InsertValues() {    
    int rc;
    // Insert Values
    rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1, 'Hello, Hurol from test1');");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);        
        return;    
    }    
}

void SelectValues() {    
    int rc;
    // Select Values
    rc = db_exec(db1, "SELECT * FROM test1");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

deleting the existing database file ...

---

// remove existing file
SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db");

---

But when the INSERT or SELECT procedure is executed on the table created without deleting the existing database, ESP8266 is reset.

---

// remove existing file
// SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db");

---

(If deletion of the existing database file is canceled)

How can I get the best document about the reset problem when using ESP8266 and SQLite?

Can you please help in this matter? Thank you from now.

Comment: It sounds like either the WDT (watchdog timer) is force-resetting your ESP, or you are attempting to access some memory that is not initialized (uninitialized variable). You appear to be doing a lot of work in the `setup()` function, which may eventually trigger the hardware WDT if file access takes too long, etc. Try calling `ESP.wdtFeed();` inside your code periodically, to see if that alleviates the issue for now - which would confirm if it's a WDT issue.

Comment: You new post shows `rst cause:1` which indicates a power issue of some sort (power cycle reset): http://iot-bits.com/esp8266/esp8266-reset-causes-rst-cause/#:~:text=rst%20cause%20%3A%201,your%20power%20supply%20is%20dodgy.

Comment: That could be provoked by something in your circuit switching on, or your PSU dropping it's voltage too much. ESP8266 consumes quite a bit of power when doing wifi functions, I believe up to 1A. How are you powering your ESP?

Comment: It looks like it has improved. Thank you very much. 

hw_wdt_disable(); void hw_wdt_disable() {
    *((volatile uint32_t*)0x60000900) &= ~(1); // Hardware WDT OFF
}

Comment: I put esp in flash mode so that the reset does not continue. (rst cause:1) so there is rst cause: 1 return.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has improved. Thank you very much.

```
hw_wdt_disable(); 

void hw_wdt_disable() { 
     ((volatile uint32_t)0x60000900) &= ~(1); // Hardware WDT OFF 
    }
```

Comment: Just note, the WDT on the ESP is enabled by default as part of the ESP platform code. It's there to ensure certain functions do not hard-lock your ESP, and might be useful in other places. You may want to try disabling the WDT when going into a function you know will always take a while to return, and then re-enable the WDT after exit. The Arduino platform disables the WDT by default, for what it's worth. That's up to you though, since you know your code best - good luck!